# Onde eu sento? No assento ou no acento?

Tags: ortografia

É comum eu ver o uso dessas duas palavras para o mesmo caso, porém qual delas é a correta?
Quando devo empregar cada termo?

It's common I see the use of these two words for the same case, but which one is correct?
When should I use each term?

Comment: Eu sento no assento e não sento no acento.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Assento` refere-se a um lugar onde se pode sentar. Deve utilizar a palavra quando quiser indicar que se referir a um lugar sentado.

Exemplo: Vou-me sentar neste assento cor de laranja.

Por sua vez, a palavra `acento` refere-se as marcas usadas para alterar o som de certas letras (tais como acento agudo ´, grave `, circunflexo ^).

Exemplo: A palavra café tem um acento agudo.